# docker exec -it コンテナ名 bashを実行すると、次の行に「root@数字:/var/www/html#」と表示されます。次の行の先頭は「$」が来てほしい。

Tags: docker

マンガでわかるDoker2の中で、
`$ docker exec -it myapp bash` を実行した後に、
`$ echo '<?php phpinfo();'> index.php` を実行し、
ブラウザで「http://localhost/」と入力してphpが動いている確認しましょうと記載があります。

私は「Docker Quickstart Terminal」を使っているのですが、
`$ docker exec -it myapp bash` を実行すると次の行に以下が表示されます。

```
root@数字:/var/www/html#
```

試しに以下を実行し、

```
root@数字:/var/www/html#　echo '<?php phpinfo();'> index.php
```

ブラウザで「http://localhost/」を入れてみたのですが、「このサイトにアクセスできません。」と表示されます。
他のサイトは確認できるのでネットにはつながっています。

C:\Users\ユーザー名\Desktop\kunren\docker\wakaba
フォルダ内にはindex.phpは作成されていました。

解決策が分からず質問させて頂きました。

Comment: 利用しているコンテナイメージ (myapp) の情報は分かりますか？ / 行の先頭に表示される部分は「プロンプト」と呼ばれる箇所で、カスタマイズも可能ですがブラウザでアクセス出来ない件と直接の関係はありません。

Comment: 申し訳ございません。利用しているコンテナイメージ (myapp) の情報が分かりません。OracleVMVirtualBOXを使っているのは関係ありますでしょうか。

Comment: 利用しているコンテナイメージ (myapp) の情報ですが、phpv7.0+apacheかと思います。「php run -d -p 80:80 --name myapp php:7.0-apache」でコンテナ作成しました。

Comment: 今以下サイトを見つけ、「ローカルアドレスにはプロキシサーバーを使用しない」にチェックを入れました。  
https://w.atwiki.jp/kodan/pages/159.html  
  
アドレス欄は空白にしてポートは80にしています。PC再起動して「http://localhost/」をアドレスバーに入れてみたのですが、
やはり「このサイトにはアクセスできません。」と表示されてしまいます。。

Answer (score 0):

以下で回答を見つけることができました。仮想マシンにポートフォワーディングの設定が必要でした。
無事localhostにアクセスすることができました。

[Windows10でDockerを起動したがlocalhostに接続できない - Qiita](https://teratail.com/questions/151484)